# install ghostscript 9.25 in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ghostscript

I come across [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571891/fail-to-execute-gs-script-for-imageick/53586576#53586576) and need to downgrade ghostscript to 9.25.

Current Ghostscript version is 9.26 but I need to install 9.25 on my Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there any way to do that properly with 'sudo apt-get install ****'?

or downloading the source code and compile is the only way?

If so, please share a guide for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The ghostscript 9.25 version is available on
[ubuntu.pkgs.org](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.10/ubuntu-main-amd64/ghostscript_9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html)
and is called
`ghostscript_9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb`.

A `.deb` installation file is available from the above page at
[this address](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/ghostscript/ghostscript_9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb).

I would advice to uninstall version 9.26 before installing this version.
I don't really know whether there will or not be a dependencies problem
with this version, but it might be worth trying.